# LINQ to SQL: Alter Table or Add New Table to Existing Database

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, alter-table

Does LINQ to SQL allow tables to be altered similar to the way tables can be created [`DataContext.CreateDatabase()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx)?

I know its bad practice to modify the database, however, new information may need to be added to our data structure. I wondered if LINQ to SQL allowed for a push system to alter existing tables?

If there is no built in LINQ to SQL class for this functionality, what isthe best way to approach this?

**Update:**

It appears as if this is not possible. I have requested a new feature to be added to the .NET Framework. Vote for it if you are also interested: connect.microsoft.com [**Feature Request**](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635612/linq-to-sql-alter-or-add-new-tables).

Also see the question [Is it possible to use Linq to ALTER a database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337652/is-it-possible-to-use-linq-to-alter-a-database-table).

Comment: So you're saying that you have an existing database, modify your data structures, recompile, and want to automatically update the database to match?

Comment: @Gabe: Yes. Perhaps with a Method like DataContext.ModifyDatabase() and it would provide the necessary SQL statements to ALTER the existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do it...I think given that LINQ is trying to abstract the structure of the db away, that's probably not the right tool.

I would just open a connection to the database and execute ALTER TABLE statements against the raw database.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, but I minor alter statements should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term for what you're looking for is "database migrations", popularized by ruby on rails.  For .Net there is [MigratorDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/).  It's not tied in to Linq To SQL (or any other ORM) at all, but it might help with what you're looking to accomplish.

Here's [some other implementations](http://flux88.com/blog/net-database-migration-tool-roundup/) for .Net

Answer (score 0):

Check out Paul Stovell's great article on [How to deploy a database](http://www.paulstovell.com/database-deployment). I've also used [SQL Deploy](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/SQLDeploy/Default.aspx) to much success in the past.

Answer (score 0):

a way to do the transfer is making a tool

1.- the tool must know the  old database schema
2.- the tool must know the   new database schema

with that just make the methods to upgrade  the  database,  here an example

```
    table Person (old)          table Person (new)
     id                           id
     name                         name
                                  age
```

then  select all from the  old database and  then create  the new rows  in the updated database

```
    new person {
       id=oldPerson.id;
       name=oldPerson.name
        age=defaultAge;
       }
```